# Adding the total of the previous month to the selected month

Tags: vba, excel

So I have here a screen shot an excel file with 2 sheets, the first is the 'YEAR Sheet' and the 2nd is the 'Monthly Report Sheet', the value of the **Target of the month** will automatically change when I change the Month or the F3 cell on Monthly report sheet. Now my problem is how can I ADD the total of the previous month to the selected month automatically. Sample screen shots is this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd search the value of `F3` on the `YEAR Sheet` in row 19 into a variable eg. actMonth, then sum the values of the 30th row from column `E` to column `actMonth-1`, and there you are.

Comment: Can we elaborate sir ?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
How did you get the data for the Target month to change? I'm asking because you could use the same formula (or VBA code) and just ad `Offset` function to it to get the correct Cell.

Option 2:
You could also use the `Match` function to get the correct column and build a formula using `Indirect`, like this: `=Indirect(Address(row_num,col_num))`:

Lookup Cell -> B25

Formula for current Month (C25) -> `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(21,MATCH(B25,$A$7:$N$7,0)))`

Formula for previous Month (D25) -> `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(21,MATCH(B25,$A$7:$N$7,0)-1))`

As you can see the only difference in these 2 formulas is the `-1` which changes the number of column .

For the Cells C24 & D24 i have used the same formula just with the row =7

[image]

Comment: This is the code from Mr. @harun24hr, to change the value of TARGET OF THE MONTH base on the month you selected, it came from my previous question 'Changing the value of the other Cell base on the month you entered' and it work for me., =IFERROR(INDEX('YEAR Sheet'!$E$21:$P$32,ROWS($E$21:$E21),MATCH(LEFT($F$3,3),'YEAR Sheet'!$E$19:$P$19,0)),"-")

Comment: Then try this (put it in the cell where the last month should be added):

`=IFERROR(INDEX('YEAR Sheet'!$E$21:$P$32,ROWS($E$21:$E21),MATCH(LEFT($F$3,3),'YEAR Sheet'!$E$19:$P$19,0))+INDEX('YEAR Sheet'!$E$21:$P$32,ROWS($E$30),MATCH(LEFT($F$3,3),'YEAR Sheet'!$E$19:$P$19,0)-1),"-")`

Comment: I have a question, the "last month value" is only the value from previous month (from the source table) or is it a year to date sum?